# How do Custom Attribute Methods work in Sails js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, waterline

According to the [documentation](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/ORM/Models.html) Custom Attribute Methods can be defined on the model, and then later used on objects returned from Queries made through Waterline, Sails JS's ORM.

This is not working for me.  I am getting the correct data back from the query but none of functions that I declare on the model work. Trying to call them results in a TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'methodName'

(Update with a clearer example)

Here is my Model with the custom Attribute method

```
module.exports = {

attributes: {
  firstName : {
    type: 'string'
  },
  lastName : {
    type: 'string'
  }
},
  // Custom Attribute Method
  fullName : function(){
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName
  }
};
```

Here is where I am using it in the controller

```
module.exports = {

  findMe: function(req, res){

    User.findOne({firstName:'Todd'}).exec(function(err, user){
      console.log(user.fullName()); //<--TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fullName'
      res.send(user);
    })
   }

};
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you include your code for how you are calling the properties

Comment: updated with a short and clear example, of the model and controller where I am using it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Full name should be included with the rest of the attributes

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
      firstName : {
        type: 'string'
      },
      lastName : {
        type: 'string'
      },
      fullName : function(){
        return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: we have all been there!

Comment: I'm still there! I've my method *right there* inside of the `attributes` block -- still says its undefined. Also, I have a `toJSON` right below returning `this.toObject()` -- is there some crazy, wacky stuff happening because I'm serializing `this`?

Comment: I am not sure this is possible, did you find it on documentation?

Comment: is this still working in sails 1.0? or is there any alternate to this in sails1.0?